# Typo3 9.5 : Multifunctional Extension

Tags: typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

Is it possible to register more than one controller in one Extension oder more than one action in one controller by any chance?

If not, why is this an array?

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'T395',
    'T395Base',
    [
        'item' => 'list'
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'item' => ''
    ]
);
```

I think there is something I didn't get after reading the first extension Guide on Typo3 official pages and supportpages for controller, flow and view. Are there any examples for having multifunctional controllers or multicontroller extensions? Maybe I'm searching with wrong keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. After some more trial and error, I found that there can be several controller in one extension - you have to register everyone as an own plugin in the extension in ext_localconf.php and tt_content.php.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can have multiple actions, which can be found in multiple extensions.

If you want it very basic: use the `EXT:extension_builder` and build a small data model where you can add the actions: `list, show, edit, delete, create` and inspect the resulting code.